# Is there a generic way to read from xml file?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am using xml files and I have different objects with different structure.
I would like to write 1 method to read all the object so the main program will use a method of the object which will call my xml class for feeling the fields of it.

This is the only method I need to generalize:

```
public static Launcher getLauncher(Node node) 
{       
    Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
        Element element = (Element) node;                     
        launcher.setIsHidden(Boolean.parseBoolean(XmlReader.getTagValue("isHidden", element)));
        launcher.setId(XmlReader.getTagValue("id", element));           
    }
    return launcher;
}
```

Launcher is my object in this case but it could be a ship or any other object.
each object has different fields of different types.

I am using DOM Parser.

Also I was wondering if this is the right way to do it?
What I have now is a main program an xml reader which gives me a node list,object classes and for each object I created anotehr class as a helper class and this class creates the object using my xml class by getting the nodes from it and parsing via hardcoding using dom parser.

Again, I am not content with it.

What is the way that used in the industry?

Comment: Which dom parser are you using?

Comment: Seems you should have a look at [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html).

Comment: Yes it seems JAXB is what your are looking for, but I would not call JAXB a generic approach - you need to create the classes Launcher and Ship, etc..